# Replacing car audio on Lancer 9

Tags: replace, audio, mitsubishi

I need to replace a car audio unit on Lancer 9.

The problem is that I have a 2-din panel, that I am unable to remove.

[image: Lancer 9 audio panel]

When I pull the panel at the mark "1" - it is being released a bit on the bottom, but something is still tightly holding it on the top side.

If I reach out to the mark "2" from the inside of a panel (reachable via opened glove box), I feel there is a philips screw there, that I assumably able to unscrew.

The question is: What else do I need to unscrew, to remove the installed audio unit?

Answer (score 2):

Panels like that are usually removed after removing the head unit. I'm guessing from the picture that it is an aftermarket unit, so you should be able to get an appropriate removal tool (these vary according to the make of the head unit) from your local car accessories shop. Use the tool(s) to remove the head unit, and you'll find a metal cage behind it, usually held in with bent metal tabs. un-bend the tabs to remove the cage, and you'll probably find the screws for the fascia panel behind it.

Comment: Nick, when you say head unit, you mean the audio player itself?

Comment: Yes, the actual stereo unit in the middle of the dash panel